# I need to create new lists with a for loop C#

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I'm creating a program that stores students and their scores in a dictionary list mixture. For example,

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> examGrades = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
List<int> name = new List<int>();
```

Is there anyway to use a for loop to to create new lists for new students?
When I'm writing code for instance

```
Console.WriteLine("What is the student name");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
List<int> name = new List<int>();
```

In this case I would get an error an unable to create because "name" already exists. Is there anyway to get around this at all? This would be in the inner for loop of a nested for loop. The outer for loops would go through and add items to the current list. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just call the list something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to **check if the dictionary already contains the key**( Student , in this case) before adding the item into the dictionary.

Use `ContainsKey` extension method of the `Dictionary`, to check if the student name already exists in the dictionary.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> studentMarks = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        string decision = "N";
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            //If you add the same key to dictionary, exception will be thrown
            if(studentMarks.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The student already exists!");
                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the marks of " + name);
            List<int> marks = new List<int>();

            int subjectCount = 5;

            //Loop until your desired count of marks has been entered
            for (int i = 0; i < subjectCount; i++)
            {
                string mark = Console.ReadLine();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mark))
                {
                    break;

                }

                int markInt = Convert.ToInt32(mark);
                marks.Add(markInt);
            }

            studentMarks.Add(name, marks);

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add details of another student? (Y/N)");
            decision = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //Keep doing until user wants to 
        while (decision == "Y");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you input, I will try this out in my code and let you know how it works!

Comment: This does work as the solution! With a touch of tweaking to tailor to my needs it works great, thank you!

Comment: That's great. Glad I was of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> examGrades = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Student's name: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Student's mark (type 0 at the end): ");
    List<int> marks = new List<int>();
    int mark = 0;
    do
    {
        int mark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if(mark == 0)
            break;
        marks.Add(mark);
    } while(true);
    examGrades.Add(name, marks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this and I'll definitely have to try this out and will let you know if it works for what I need! I appreciate the help.